# Database connection fail given errorno. 24

Tags: php, mysql, database

In my fedora server when I upload a large excel file then all of my database connection is failed. I didnot get this type of error in previous 3 years. I am getting

> ERROR] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Can't open file:
>   './timesheet/emp_timesheet.frm' (errno: 24)

In my.cnf file already set

> max_allowed_packet = 1073741824

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/not-enough-file-handles.html) maybe it helps.

Comment: Thanks jens I am setting open_file_limit let see this error coming or not in future.